# Bootstrap equal column heights using row-eq-height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/

I don't understand why .row-eq-height isn't working for me in the Jsbin.
Anyone know why this isn't working?

https://jsbin.com/ravudobovo/edit?html,output

Comment: As per that link, it needs this extra css `.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
}` https://jsbin.com/tilekuzibo/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported by the Bootstrap that Jsbin loads.  Just add the custom `.row-eq-height` declaration to the CSS and it works: https://jsbin.com/xosuyituwu/edit?html,css,output

Link to eq-height column css: http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/equal-height-columns.css